# Google Apps Script Sign-in to external website and pull HTML data

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to use GAS to login to a website and pull the resulting HTML data.

However, when I try to check the content of the variable, it's returning the login page HTML, and not the page it was supposed to scrape.

```
    function myFunction() {
  var payload =
   {
     "login-username" : "test",
     "login-password" : "test&2",
   };
  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false,
     'Connection':'keep-alive',
  };

 var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/login/authenticate" , options);
  var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
    Logger.log(sessionDetails)

  var headers = {'Cookie':sessionDetails};
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/show/11267", 
                                  {"headers" : {"Cookie" : headers},
                                  }).getContentText()
  
  }
```

Logger returns the following data:

```
[20-07-31 04:05:18:778 PDT] [AWSALB=2HLsO1B+Kq49m+t7/KKp6kTTBa3eIEPoEut2toxswn0hltUoNiPEmpB5mejREwHeKiNcTodw4Pp45V4BuCH0ghtFBXMsOv/QVgXHflnoGFNWz6tkoihb6rWcrgxm; Expires=Fri, 07 Aug 2020 11:05:18 GMT; Path=/, AWSALBCORS=2HLsO1B+Kq49m+t7/KKp6kTTBa3eIEPoEut2toxswn0hltUoNiPEmpB5mejREwHeKiNcTodw4Pp45V4BuCH0ghtFBXMsOv/QVgXHflnoGFNWz6tkoihb6rWcrgxm; Expires=Fri, 07 Aug 2020 11:05:18 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure, grails_remember_me=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/, JSESSIONID=04EDD97E73F639B4717771E7933435F3; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly]
```

[image]

I'm thinking it's due to the cookies, I also looked at other posts here but I wasn't able to make it work.

I'm still a beginner at this, it would be appreciated if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can it be that you are trying to pull the data before the authentication completes? Have you tried only pulling the data once you are signed in?

Comment: @Kessy Hmm I did initially add an if condition to wait for a status code, but I was getting the same results. I'll give it another go, thank you